# How about a badge for standing by an unpopular answer?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Regarding subjective questions, if you post an answer and get a lot of downvotes, your reputation take a hit, right?  Well, what if you want to stand by your answer?  It's not offensive because it isn't flagged as such, but for whatever reason it just rubs some people the wrong way, and they downvote it.

If you've got the *cojones* to stand behind your answer regardless of how it effects your rep, how about a badge for that?  Maybe something like, being downvoted 5 times but leaving your answer up for a certain period of time after the 5th downvote.

Comment: it's 'cojones'           .

Comment: actually shouldn't there be an accent or something somewhere? Maybe I should have babblefished it.

Comment: Skip the Spanish and just go with "testicular fortitude". ;)

Comment: @bpapa It's correct as Juan Manual wrote it.

Comment: How about a "learned by fire" for asking a question with -10 or more =P

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered that on most of the sites (not necessarily meta) you are getting downvoted because you are wrong? Why would we want to reward someone for being wrong AND stubborn?

It should also be noted that you can't differentiate badges based on whether or not the question/answer is subjective in nature.

I suggested a badge at one time called Purple Heart which would be awarded for an accepted answer that was at -5 (yes it has happened several times) and that seemed to get a good response from the community.

Your suggestion sounds more like "Punching Bag" than anything.

Comment: Either way, subjective or not, you have the stones to stand behind the answer in some cases. It's just one badge.

Comment: Badges are not meant to reward bad behavior. Leaving an answer up that is getting heavily downvoted (which would imply a lot of people think it is **wrong** is not exactly a desired behavior).

Comment: Hah... "punching bag"...

Comment: As an example, look at this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39758/what-does-google-chrome-mean-to-web-developers/39813#39813  It's my opinion, which is what the guy asked for. Can't be right or wrong. It's not popular because I imply that most people that write about technology are using a Mac (which they are), but it's still neither right or wrong.

Comment: When you can develop an algorithm that can detect when an answer is actually correct and/or subjective despite all the downvotes it is getting, maybe you would have a point. But I don't think that will ever be the case.

Comment: @bpapa: well, that's an even better reason not to award badges - that question is inappropriately subjective and shouldn't be encouraged either!

Comment: "It's just one badge", then it doesn't need to exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The badges are designed to reward desired behavior - leaving a post up that is unfavored by the community doesn't exactly seem desirable to me.

The bigger problem, however, is I don't think there's a good (algorithmic) way to determine when someone is *standing by their opinion* vs. when they're simply *wrong*.

While I do understand your position and agree *if it were feasible*, I think this is a recipe for disaster. Also, I think the question should have to have the `subjective` tag to even consider awarding this badge.

Comment: The tags can be added and removed at any time by almost anybody. Tying it to the tag would likely lead to someone getting voted down to oblivion on purpose, switching the tag to subjective, and then getting a badge.

Comment: Very true. And there would either be a way to guard against this, or it furthers my point that this is just not easily automate-able and a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just stop asking and answering subjective questions. It is that simple.

There should be no reward at all either way for interacting with this junk.

Comment: I see your point, but like 'em or not, as far as I can tell subjective questions are allowed and don't seem to be on the path to being disallowed any time soon.

Comment: @Bpapa: What in the world are you talking about? Subjective questions have been disallowed since the site first started. From the FAQ: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!"

Comment: @bpapa: Have you even /read/ the FAQ? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: nope. but there are subjective questions all over SO.

Comment: @bpapa: Appealing to common practice is a logical fallacy. I know people are drinking and driving all over my state tonight, but that does not mean I am allowed to drink and drive.

Comment: @Rich B: "Your Honor, I readily admit to killing those 12 people, and I know the law says it is illegal, but a lot of people have committed murder."  "They have?  Well, case dismissed!"

Comment: logix iz 2 hurd!!1!

Comment: About 5000 questions tagged as subjective, making it somewhere around the #15 most popular tag on the site. Since this is a user-driven site, the users are going to drive. A lot of people (obviously) don't like subjective questions but they continue to get posted and popular. So, clearly a lot of people do like subjective questions that got posted here. So add some bells and whistles around it.

Comment: bpapa is right. Meta discussion should focus on how we manage reality. It is *not* true that we manage subjective questions by closing them. Should I go to the programmer cartoon question and vote to close it as "subjective and argumentative"? Come on, the link is there. Shouldn't we all do it? We can close it just with a couple votes more. This is not reality. This is not the SO reality. And by the way the original post is not limited to subjective questions. Given that bpapa states what _reality_ is, he has a point, and your invocation of basic logic was unnecessary.

Comment: @bpapa: Again, do you not understand something about the FAQ and mission statement of this site? It is very clear. If only you could see how many of that tag have been closed and deleted.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you should, and it wouldn't be the first time for that question either. Read the FAQ. Let it guide you. This is not difficult stuff. And yes, bringing up the fact that bpapa is using a logical fallacy to try and prove a point is very necessary.

Comment: @rich I actually understand it pretty well, since it's been linked to and explained in these comments a few times now. however, as Daniel points out it is not the reality of the site. I'm sorry that it offends you so much but it doesn't offend many other people, so ignoring the popularity of subjective questions would be rather foolhardy. Some logic could be that people like subjective questions, so let's do something that makes them happy.

Comment: @bpapa: You will have to take that up with the founders of the site. If they want to change SO.com into a discussion forum, we will go with that. Otherwise, a programming Q&A site needs real questions.

Comment: Your honor, the building was already on fire, and probably would have burned down anyway. My decision to throw gasoline on it was merely in keeping with the reality of the situation.

Comment: @bpapa: people love to participate. Everyone gets to participate in a subjective question, 'cause there's no wrong answer (just... very unpopular answers). If ya got tha gonads to post an unpopular answer to a question you know is nothing but a popularity contest, then go for it. Heck, if i see it, maybe i'll even toss in an extra down-vote for you, just to help you prove that you're a man. But don't expect a prize for it - that goes to the guy who *stays on the horse the longest*, not the one who gets kicked in the face the most...

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...a badge for being "wrong and stubborn" - sounds like the "*pointy-haired boss badge*"!

Comment: I think it should be named after me.

Comment: I find it funny how the person who suggested it deserves the badge for the very suggestion.